# "Computed Properties" in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I recently chose AngularJS over ember.js for a project I am working on, and have been very pleased with it so far.  One nice thing about ember is its built in support for "computed properties" with automatic data binding.  I have been able to accomplish something similar in Angular with the code below, but am not sure if it is the best way to do so.

```
// Controller
angular.module('mathSkills.controller', [])
  .controller('nav', ['navigation', '$scope', function (navigation, $scope) {
    // "Computed Property"
    $scope.$watch(navigation.getCurrentPageNumber, function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
      scope.currentPageNumber = newVal;
    });
    $scope.totalPages = navigation.getTotalPages();
  }]);

// 'navigation' service
angular.module('mathSkills.services', [])
  .factory('navigation', function() {
    var currentPage = 0,
        pages = [];

    return {
      getCurrentPageNumber: function() {
        return currentPage + 1;
      },
      getTotalPages: function() {
        return pages.length;
      }
    };
  });

// HTML template
<div id=problemPager ng-controller=nav>
  Problem {{currentPageNumber}} of {{totalPages}}
</div>
```

I would like for the UI to update whenever the `currentPage` of the `navigation` service changes, which the above code accomplishes.

Is this the best way to solve this problem in AngularJS?  Are there (significant) performance implications for using `$watch()` like this?  Would something like this be better accomplished using custom events and `$emit()` or `$broadcast()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I found the answer.  This example can be dramatically simplified to:

```
// Controller
angular.module('mathSkills.controller', [])
  .controller('nav', ['navigation', '$scope', function (navigation, $scope) {
    // Property is now just a reference to the service's function.
    $scope.currentPageNumber = navigation.getCurrentPageNumber;
    $scope.totalPages = navigation.getTotalPages();
  }]);

// HTML template
// Notice the first binding is to the result of a function call.
<div id=problemPager ng-controller=nav>
  Problem {{currentPageNumber()}} of {{totalPages}}
</div>
```

Comment: That's better indeed.
However, why do you stick everything together ?
Maybe you should try to separate your module and your controller declaractions ?

Comment: Well, the module is the module for the controller; instead of keeping a top level controller.

Comment: This could have performance implications since Angular.js doesn't know if the value returned by `currentPageNumber()` has changed, so it has to call it on every digest cycle.

Answer (score 31):

While your self-answer works, it doesn't actually implement computed properties. You simply solved the problem by calling a function in your binding to force the binding to be greedy. I'm not 100% sure it'd work in all cases, and the greediness might have unwanted performance characteristics in some situations.

I worked up a solution for a computed properties w/dependencies similar to what EmberJS has:

```
function ngCreateComputedProperty($scope, computedPropertyName, dependentProperties, f) {
  function assignF($scope) {
    var computedVal = f($scope);
    $scope[computedPropertyName] = computedVal;
  };

  $scope.$watchCollection(dependentProperties, function(newVal, oldVal, $scope) {
    assignF($scope);
  });
  assignF($scope);
};

// in some controller...
ngCreateComputedProperty($scope, 'aSquared', 'a',     function($scope) { return $scope.a * $scope.a } );
ngCreateComputedProperty($scope, 'aPlusB',   '[a,b]', function($scope) { return $scope.a + $scope.b } );
```

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/apinstein/2kR2c/3/

It's worth noting that $scope.$watchCollection is efficient -- I verified that "assignF()" is called only once even if multiple dependencies are changed simultaneously (same $apply cycle).
"

Comment: Excellent. Just wondering under what object do you declare these custom functions (in comparison to global object in the example)? is there a recommended practice for this in angular?

Answer (score 5):

Note that with ECMAScript 5 you can now also do something like this:

```
// Controller
angular.module('mathSkills.controller', [])
  .controller('nav', function(navigation, $scope) {
    $scope.totalPages = navigation.getTotalPages();
    Object.defineProperty($scope, 'currentPageNumber', {
      get: function() {
        return navigation.getCurrentPageNumber();
      }
    });
  ]);

//HTML
<div ng-controller="nav">Problem {{currentPageNumber}} of {{totalPages}}</div>
```